# Want to install DNN 7 but getting error of Configuration Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I am trying to install dnn 7 but it gives me a a error of

**Description:** An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

**Parser Error Message:** It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error:

Line 118:
Line 119:  
Line 120:    
Line 121:

Source File: D:\DNN_Platform_07.04.00_Install\web.config    Line: 120

```
<configuration>
  <!-- register local configuration handlers -->
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="dotnetnuke">
      <!-- the requirePermission attribute will cause a syntax warning - please ignore - it is required for Medium Trust support-->
      <section name="data" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke"/>
      <section name="logging" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke"/>
      <section name="scheduling" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke"/>
      <section name="htmlEditor" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke"/>
      <section name="navigationControl" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke"/>
      <section name="searchIndex" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke"/>
      <section name="searchDataStore" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke"/>
      <section name="friendlyUrl" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke"/>
      <section name="caching" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke"/>
      <section name="authentication" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke"/>
      <section name="members" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke"/>
      <section name="roles" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke"/>
      <section name="profiles" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke"/>
      <section name="permissions" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke"/>
      <section name="moduleCaching" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="outputCaching" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="folder" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="clientcapability" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
      <section name="sitemap" requirePermission="false" type="DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers.ProviderConfigurationHandler, DotNetNuke" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor">
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <!-- Connection String for SQL Server 2008/2012 Express -->
    <add name="SiteSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=DB Path;Initial Catalog=DNN;User Id=sa;Password=sa@123;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <!-- Connection String for SQL Server 2008/2012
    <add name="SiteSqlServer" connectionString="Server=(local);Database=DotNetNuke;uid=;pwd=;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
    -->
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <!-- Connection String for SQL Server 2008/2012 Express - kept for backwards compatability - legacy modules   -->
    <add key="SiteSqlServer" value="Data Source=DB Path;Initial Catalog=DNN;User Id=sa;Password=sa@123;"/>
    <!-- Connection String for SQL Server 2008/2012 - kept for backwards compatability - legacy modules
    <add key="SiteSqlServer" value="Server=(local);Database=DotNetNuke;uid=;pwd=;"/>
    -->
    <add key="InstallTemplate" value="DotNetNuke.install.config"/>
    <add key="AutoUpgrade" value="true"/>
    <add key="UseInstallWizard" value="true"/>
    <add key="InstallMemberRole" value="true"/>
    <add key="ShowMissingKeys" value="false"/>
    <add key="EnableCachePersistence" value="false"/>
    <add key="HostHeader" value=""/>
    <!-- Host Header to remove from URL so "www.mydomain.com/johndoe/Default.aspx" is treated as "www.mydomain.com/Default.aspx" -->
    <add key="RemoveAngleBrackets" value="false"/>
    <!--optionally strip angle brackets on public login and registration screens-->
    <add key="PersistentCookieTimeout" value="0"/>
    <!--use as persistent cookie expiration. Value is in minutes, and only active if a non-zero figure-->
    <!-- set UsePortNumber to true to preserve the port number if you're using a port number other than 80 (the standard)
        <add key="UsePortNumber" value="true" /> -->
    <!-- Services Framework Tracing is primarily useful for developing and debugging -->
    <add key="EnableServicesFrameworkTracing" value="false" />
      <add key="UpdateServiceUrl" value="http://update.dotnetnuke.com" />
    <add key="Telerik.Web.UI.ScriptFolders" value="~/Portals;" />
    <add key="Telerik.Web.SkinsAssembly" value="Telerik.Web.UI.Skins, Version=2013.2.717.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="loginUrl" value="~/Login.aspx" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="DotNetNuke.Web.Razor.DotNetNukeWebPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="WebMatrix.Data" />
        <add namespace="Microsoft.Web.Helpers" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <!-- The system.webServer section is required for IIS7 compatability It is ignored by IIS6-->
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
    <modules>
      <add name="RequestFilter" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.RequestFilter.RequestFilterModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="UrlRewrite" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.UrlRewriteModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="MobileRedirect" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.MobileRedirectModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="Exception" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.Exceptions.ExceptionModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="UsersOnline" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.UsersOnline.UsersOnlineModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="DNNMembership" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.Membership.MembershipModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="Personalization" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.Personalization.PersonalizationModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="Analytics" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.Analytics.AnalyticsModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="Services" type="DotNetNuke.HttpModules.Services.ServicesModule, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" />
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />     
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
      <add name="LogoffHandler*" path="Logoff.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Authentication.LogOffHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add name="RSSHandler" path="RSS.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Syndication.RssHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add name="LinkClickHandler" path="LinkClick.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.FileSystem.FileServerHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add name="CaptchaHandler" path="*.captcha.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.UI.WebControls.CaptchaHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" path="ChartImage.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="UserProfilePageHandler" path="User.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.UserProfile.UserProfilePageHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add name="RadProgressHandler" verb="*" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.Upload.RadUploadProgressHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add name="UserProfilePicHandler" path="ProfilePic.ashx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.UserProfile.UserProfilePicHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="SitemapHandler" path="Sitemap.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Sitemap.SitemapHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <machineKey validationKey="F9D1A2D3E1D3E2F7B3D9F90FF3965ABDAC304902" decryptionKey="F9D1A2D3E1D3E2F7B3D9F90FF3965ABDAC304902F8D923AC" decryption="3DES" validation="SHA1"/>
    <!-- set code access security trust level - this is generally set in the machine.config
    <trust level="Full" originUrl=".*" />
    -->
    <!-- set debugmode to false for running application -->
    <compilation debug="false" strict="false" targetFramework="4.0">
      <buildProviders>
        <remove extension=".resx" />
        <remove extension=".resources" />
      </buildProviders>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
      </assemblies>
      <expressionBuilders >
        <add expressionPrefix="dnnLoc" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Localization.LocalizationExpressionBuilder, DotNetNuke"/>
      </expressionBuilders>
    </compilation>
    <!-- permits errors to be displayed for remote clients -->
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />
    <!-- Forms or Windows authentication -->
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".DOTNETNUKE" protection="All" timeout="60" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
    </authentication>
    <!--
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows">
    </authentication>
    -->
    <!-- allow large file uploads -->
    <httpRuntime shutdownTimeout="120" executionTimeout="1200" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" maxRequestLength="29296" requestLengthDiskThreshold="81920" requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,:,\,?" enableVersionHeader="false"  requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" domain=""/>
    <!--  GLOBALIZATION
    This section sets the globalization settings of the application. 
    Utf-8 is not supported on Netscape 4.x 
    If you need netscape compatiblity leave iso-8859-1.
    UTF-8 is recommended for complex languages
    -->
    <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en" requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" fileEncoding="UTF-8"/>
    <!--<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en"  fileEncoding="iso-8859-1" requestEncoding="iso-8859-1" responseEncoding="iso-8859-1"/>-->
    <!-- page level options -->
    <pages validateRequest="false" enableViewStateMac="true" enableEventValidation="true"  viewStateEncryptionMode="Always">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.ComponentModel"/>
        <add namespace="System.Data"/>
        <add namespace="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
        <add namespace="System.Drawing"/>
        <add namespace="Microsoft.VisualBasic"/>
        <add namespace="System.Globalization"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Services.Localization"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Entities.Users"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Common"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Data"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Framework"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Modules"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Security"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Services"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.UI"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions"/>
        <add namespace="DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs"/>
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <!-- ASP.NET 2 Membership/Profile/Role and AnonymousAuthentication Providers -->
    <!-- anonymousIdentification configuration:
          enabled="[true|false]"                              Feature is enabled?
          cookieName=".ASPXANONYMOUS"                         Cookie Name
          cookieTimeout="100000"                              Cookie Timeout in minutes
          cookiePath="/"                                      Cookie Path
          cookieRequireSSL="[true|false]"                     Set Secure bit in Cookie
          cookieSlidingExpiration="[true|false]"              Reissue expiring cookies?
          cookieProtection="[None|Validation|Encryption|All]" How to protect cookies from being read/tampered
          domain="[domain]"                                   Enables output of the "domain" cookie attribute set to the specified value
        -->
    <anonymousIdentification enabled="true" cookieName=".ASPXANONYMOUS" cookieTimeout="100000" cookiePath="/" cookieRequireSSL="false" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" cookieProtection="None" domain=""/>
    <membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <!-- Configuration for AspNetSqlMembershipProvider:
                connectionStringName="string"               Name corresponding to the entry in <connectionStrings> section where the connection string for the provider is specified
                maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="int"            The number of failed password attempts, or failed password answer attempts that are allowed before locking out a user?s account
                passwordAttemptWindow="int"                 The time window, in minutes, during which failed password attempts and failed password answer attempts are tracked
                enablePasswordRetrieval="[true|false]"      Should the provider support password retrievals
                enablePasswordReset="[true|false]"          Should the provider support password resets
                requiresQuestionAndAnswer="[true|false]"    Should the provider require Q & A
                minRequiredPasswordLength="int"             The minimum password length
                minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="int"  The minimum number of non-alphanumeric characters
                applicationName="string"                    Optional string to identity the application: defaults to Application Metabase path
                requiresUniqueEmail="[true|false]"          Should the provider require a unique email to be specified
                passwordFormat="[Clear|Hashed|Encrypted]"   Storage format for the password: Hashed (SHA1), Clear or Encrypted (Triple-DES)
                description="string"                        Description of what the provider does
                -->
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="SiteSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" applicationName="DotNetNuke" description="Stores and retrieves membership data from the local Microsoft SQL Server database"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="bin;bin\HttpModules;bin\Providers;bin\Modules;bin\Support;"/>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Web.UI" publicKeyToken="121fae78165ba3d4" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2008.0.0.0-2020.0.0.0" newVersion="2013.2.717.40" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

  <dotnetnuke>
    <htmlEditor defaultProvider="DotNetNuke.RadEditorProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="DotNetNuke.RadEditorProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Providers.RadEditorProvider.EditorProvider, DotNetNuke.RadEditorProvider" providerPath="~/DesktopModules/Admin/RadEditorProvider" />
      </providers>
    </htmlEditor>
    <navigationControl defaultProvider="DNNMenuNavigationProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="DNNDropDownNavigationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.NavigationControl.DNNDropDownNavigationProvider, DotNetNuke.DNNDropDownNavigationProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\NavigationProviders\DNNDropDownNavigationProvider\"/>
        <add name="ASP2MenuNavigationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.NavigationControl.ASP2MenuNavigationProvider, DotNetNuke.ASP2MenuNavigationProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\NavigationProviders\ASP2MenuNavigationProvider\"/>
        <add name="DNNMenuNavigationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.NavigationControl.DNNMenuNavigationProvider, DotNetNuke.DNNMenuNavigationProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\NavigationProviders\DNNMenuNavigationProvider\"/>
        <add name="DNNTreeNavigationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.NavigationControl.DNNTreeNavigationProvider, DotNetNuke.DNNTreeNavigationProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\NavigationProviders\DNNTreeNavigationProvider\"/>
        <add name="SolpartMenuNavigationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.NavigationControl.SolpartMenuNavigationProvider, DotNetNuke.SolpartMenuNavigationProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\NavigationProviders\SolpartMenuNavigationProvider\"/>
      </providers>
    </navigationControl>
    <searchIndex defaultProvider="ModuleIndexProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="ModuleIndexProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Search.ModuleIndexer, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\SearchProviders\ModuleIndexer\"/>
      </providers>
    </searchIndex>
    <searchDataStore defaultProvider="SearchDataStoreProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SearchDataStoreProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Search.SearchDataStore, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\SearchProviders\SearchDataStore\"/>
      </providers>
    </searchDataStore>
    <data defaultProvider="SqlDataProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SqlDataProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke" connectionStringName="SiteSqlServer" upgradeConnectionString="" providerPath="~\Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider\" objectQualifier="" databaseOwner="dbo"/>
      </providers>
    </data>
    <logging defaultProvider="DBLoggingProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="DBLoggingProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Log.EventLog.DBLoggingProvider, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\LoggingProviders\DBLoggingProvider\"/>
      </providers>
    </logging>
    <scheduling defaultProvider="DNNScheduler">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="DNNScheduler" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Scheduling.DNNScheduler, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\SchedulingProviders\DNNScheduler\" debug="false" maxThreads="1" delayAtAppStart="60" />
      </providers>
    </scheduling>
    <friendlyUrl defaultProvider="DNNFriendlyUrl">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="DNNFriendlyUrl" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Url.FriendlyUrl.DNNFriendlyUrlProvider, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" includePageName="true" regexMatch="[^a-zA-Z0-9 _-]" urlFormat="advanced"/>
      </providers>
    </friendlyUrl>
    <caching defaultProvider="FileBasedCachingProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="FileBasedCachingProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Cache.FBCachingProvider, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\CachingProviders\FileBasedCachingProvider\"/>
      </providers>
    </caching>
    <authentication defaultProvider="ADSIAuthenticationProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="ADSIAuthenticationProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Authentication.ActiveDirectory.ADSI.ADSIProvider, DotNetNuke.Authentication.ActiveDirectory" providerPath="~\Providers\AuthenticationProviders\ADSIProvider\"/>
      </providers>
    </authentication>
    <members defaultProvider="AspNetMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetMembershipProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Security.Membership.AspNetMembershipProvider, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\MembershipProviders\AspNetMembershipProvider\"/>
      </providers>
    </members>
    <roles defaultProvider="DNNRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="DNNRoleProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Security.Roles.DNNRoleProvider, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\MembershipProviders\DNNMembershipProvider\"/>
      </providers>
    </roles>
    <profiles defaultProvider="DNNProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="DNNProfileProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Security.Profile.DNNProfileProvider, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\MembershipProviders\DNNProfileProvider\"/>
      </providers>
    </profiles>
    <permissions defaultProvider="CorePermissionProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="CorePermissionProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Security.Permissions.CorePermissionProvider, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\PermissionProviders\CorePermissionProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </permissions>
    <moduleCaching defaultProvider="FileModuleCachingProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="FileModuleCachingProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.ModuleCache.FileProvider, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\ModuleCachingProviders\FileModuleCachingProvider\" />
        <add name="MemoryModuleCachingProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.ModuleCache.MemoryProvider, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\ModuleCachingProviders\MemoryModuleCachingProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </moduleCaching>
    <outputCaching defaultProvider="FileOutputCachingProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </outputCaching>
    <folder defaultProvider="StandardFolderProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="StandardFolderProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.FileSystem.StandardFolderProvider, DotNetNuke" />
        <add name="SecureFolderProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.FileSystem.SecureFolderProvider, DotNetNuke" />
        <add name="DatabaseFolderProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.FileSystem.DatabaseFolderProvider, DotNetNuke" />
      </providers>
    </folder>
    <clientcapability defaultProvider="FiftyOneClientCapabilityProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="FiftyOneClientCapabilityProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Providers.FiftyOneClientCapabilityProvider.FiftyOneClientCapabilityProvider, DotNetNuke.Providers.FiftyOneClientCapabilityProvider" providerPath="~\Providers\ClientCapabilityProviders\FiftyOneClientCapabilityProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </clientcapability>
    <sitemap defaultProvider="coreSitemapProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="coreSitemapProvider" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Sitemap.CoreSitemapProvider, DotNetNuke" providerPath="~\Providers\MembershipProviders\Sitemap\CoreSitemapProvider\" />
      </providers>
    </sitemap>
  </dotnetnuke>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You really need to provide more information. E. g. show us the web.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create a virtual directory in an existing website in IIS? If so, convert your dnn site folder to an application or create a fresh website in IIS.